# What are these coaxial connectors called?

Tags: connector, automotive, cables

I know these are coaxial and probably SMB, however, I'd like to know how each particular type of connector is called.

[image]

Moreover, I was wondering if these colors mean anything in particular (i.e. if there is a specific color-coding convention).

[image]

Edit: **Some context**. The device is a car infotainment system. The device for #1 is a GPS antenna, and 1 through 5 are the adaptors I currently have to be able to connect the GPS antenna to the system (dark-yellow-ish connector & port). **Thing is I need to get more GPS antennas and I don't think I'd really need all these cables (2 through 4) if I just had #5 instead of #1 directly in the GPS antenna**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This connectors are based on the USCAR and FAKRA standards, that are normally used in the automotive industry.

This is  brief introduction of these standards:

> The automotive industry has been revolutionized with the increased adoption of telematics in vehicles including 
>   GPS, Cellular, Bluetooth and Satellite Radio. No longer are satellite navigation systems and sophisticated in-vehicle 
>   entertainment confined solely to the luxury end of the market.
>   As telematic advancements become more reliable, available and inexpensive, vehicles are transforming into an 
>   intelligent platform for enabling mobile life. With these recent advancements in communications technology and 
>   increased consumer demand for a diverse array of on-board telematics services, RF communications systems have 
>   become integral components of today’s automobile, trucking, watercraft, motorcycle and off-road construction markets. 
>   To keep RF interconnection costs low, and to ensure high levels of electrical and mechanical performance for 
>   telematics applications, such as Global Positioning Satellite, Satellite Radio, Vehicular Internet Access, Remote vehicle 
>   diagnostics and Bluetooth, the worldwide automotive industries have standardized a high-performing, cost-effective 
>   RF connector based on the FAKRA and USCAR standards. 
>   Utilizing a modified metal SMB connector embedded within a plastic housing that can be designed with multiple 
>   color codes for easy identification, FAKRA connectors are designed to perform up to 6 GHz and meet the particular 
>   mechanical and environmental requirements of the automotive industry.

The most common applications include:

- **AM/FM Radio**
- **Satellite Radio**
- **GPS**
- **Cellular/PCS** (Personal Communications Service)
- **Bluetooth**
- **Wireless Remote**
- **Vehicle Controls**
- **WiFi**

Answer (score 4):

1, 2 and 5 look like [SMB](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.wellshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/smb-connector-plug-50-75.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.wellshow.com/technical-support/rf_connector-smb-connector/&h=371&w=455&sz=25&tbnid=jU9x5qiU66S-mM%3a&tbnh=96&tbnw=118&zoom=1&docid=WSXvSnfe0hgSqM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3HZ-T97kLsW7twf51_CWBg&sqi=2&ved=0CIoBEPUBMAQ&dur=367) (1 and 5 are male 2 is female)

3 and 4 are [SMA](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=944&bih=893&tbm=isch&tbnid=QzrTTb1Tj-GjxM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.wellshow.com/technical-support/connector-support/what-is-an-sma-connector/&docid=qbhVfv03HZ8dbM&imgurl=http://www.wellshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/sma-connector-plug.jpg&w=630&h=569&ei=dXd-T7rpHo2o8gSysJGsDg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=579&vpy=277&dur=1847&hovh=213&hovw=236&tx=89&ty=160&sig=116863031208852103049&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=141&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:0,i:150) (3 is male 4 is female)

For your color coding I would say that they are probably manufacturer spicific. If you could post the device model and manufacturer I could get more info for you. Also the purpose for the device would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

#1 and #2 I'm not familiar with.

#3 is SMA (male).

#4 is SMA (female).

#5 *looks like* SMB, but with a housing around it that isn't part of a "standard" SMB connector. It may in fact be entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

I think 1, 2, and 5 are the same type, if perhaps different genders. 
I haven't seen them before, either. I'd guess they're SMB too, with a custom housing to prevent them from connecting incorrectly.

If you look at the A, B, C, D connectors, the internal connector structure is the same across all of them (looks like SMB too), but the polarizing pins on the plastic shield is in a different place on each. It looks like someone's "clever" attempt at making it so you cannot connect cables to them incorrectly.

I really, really doubt there is a color-coding convention. At least, I haven't herd of any.

What is this equipment, anyways?

Comment: From the looks of the connectors, and the networking equipment in the background, this is some strange type of antenna distribution system, but your guess is as good as mine...